# How to send variables from one servlet to another?

Tags: jsp, servlets, session-variables

I am setting values in session attributes on one servlet ,dispatching to another servlet,retrieving and using them on second servlet then going to JSP page. All is working fine so far. 
  But I need to remove session from the code.Now problem is how to carry those fields which I were setting in session on first servlet to JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

Transfer the data from servlet to servlet using parameters and use request attributes (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)) to transfer the values to the JSP.

```
request.setAttribute('myrequestattr', 'foobar');
request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

You can use the request attributes directly in EL from  the JSP page, for example

```
<c:out value="${myrequestattr}" />
```